# Windows Hex Viewer/Editor with Map of data & Regex Searching, preferrably Portable

Tags: windows, gratis, portable, regex, hex-viewer

I am trying to find a Windows hex viewer/editor that:

- Can display the binary/hex contents of a *file* **or** *drive* in a format similar to the way WinMerge gives an overview of the differences between each file (i.e., colour where there is 1's[Dec]/not 0's[Hex] and no colour where there is 0's)
- Allows regex searches of the binary/hex contents of a file or drive, for matches to something like [`0+$`](https://www.myregextester.com/?r=f6fe7a29)
- [Ideally] Portable, i.e., Non install

... and is free. Too much to ask for?

Comment: Only 1/3 requirements, so I'm posting this as a comment. [FAR Manager](http://www.farmanager.com/) + [HexEditor Plug-in](http://plugring.farmanager.com/plugin.php?pid=120&l=en) would allow you to have a portable hex viewer and editor. However, it doesn't support colorful file comparison or regex search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are looking for such a tool, I can recommend my Hextor ( https://github.com/digitalw0lf/hextor/releases/latest ).

It can open files, logical and physical drives;
It can show graphical (bitmap) view of a file (fit about 100 MB of data on screen);
It supports searching for patterns similar to RegExp for binary data, for example `{u8:0:1..1000}` - find up to 1000 zero bytes;
And much more, like structure viewing and file compare.

It's free and you can copy installed app to run from removable media.

(upd) It's my pet project, so feedback and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Welcome Grigoriy!  I appears you are the author of this tool.  If this is correct, please disclose your affiliation within your answer *(update: now disclosed!)*.  BTW, very nice looking tool!  Upvoted! Thanks, and again, welcome!

Comment: And just like that. Seemingly exactly what was asked for (though now I am trying to remember why I asked for this ;) ), and seemingly written in the first GUI language I learned. Accepted answer is your "prize", with my thanks.

Comment: @user66001 When I read Grigoriy's answer to your nearly 6 year old question, I was happy for Grigoriy and myself, because this looks like a very useful tool.  But I was concerned that you might not see Grigoriy's answer and to learn about their fine project, as you posted your question so long ago.  A warm smile illuminated my face when I saw your comment that you did receive Grigoriy's answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) with the [Hex Editor plugin](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php?title=Plugin_Central#HexEditor).

It is completely portable, free (gratis), open-source, and meets all your requirements.

*Update (2021): Over the years, I have found quite a few bugs in both Notepad++ and its Hex Editor plugin.  So have others.  Because of this, there are currently over 1000 unfixed bugs in those packages, and many will likely never get fixed.  As such, this is still a workable solution, but I suggest looking at alternatives as well.*

Alternatives include:

1. [Hex Editor XVI32](http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm), which meets all your requirements (including portability), except it does not have full regex searches.  It does have wildcard search, which has its pros and cons when compared to regex.
2. [HXD Hex Editor](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/), which meets all your requirements (including portability), except it does not have regex search (or I was unable to make it work!).

Also, as you discovered, WinMerge does have excellent hex editing capabilities.  I recommend the [WinMerge2011 fork](https://bitbucket.org/jtuc/winmerge2011/downloads), as it has significant improvements and bug fixes over the original WinMerge.

If you are looking for a ***sector editor*** (to edit raw sectors on a drive), then I recommend [Active Disk Editor](http://www.disk-editor.org/).  It is rather amazing.  It will allow you to view raw sectors in a layout similar to the one that WinMerge2011 uses to view files.  It includes full-featured regular expression (regex) and wildcard searches, for maximum flexibility.  It is gratis (freeware), and is available for both Windows and Linux.  Good stuff.

Comment: Thanks RockPaperLizard (or should I say Sheldon ;), I will check out Notepad++ and that plugin. Also both WinMerge's (have up until now just used this for file comparisons). However, as I have tried XVI32 & HxD I am wondering if we are on the same page in regards to the 'Mapping' of the data. What I mean by that is a visual overview of where data is (non zero filled sectors) and is not (zero filled). Another example of the desired view would be some Defragmenter programs, and how they show the files that are contiguous/aren't/free space, etc. Is this what you were thinking of when answering?

Comment: Sorry, also, XVI32 doesn't seem to be able to open up a drive, instead of just a file. Does Notepad++ and WinMerge have the same limitation?

Comment: @user66001  Are you perhaps looking for a sector editor?

Comment: Perhaps RockPaperLizard. I was unaware of the this ¿sub-category? of hex editor until now, but after looking it up the feature sets of this type of program do seem more inline with my purpose. Do you also have some suggestions for these that fit my criteria?

Comment: @user66001 Yes, absolutely.  I appended my answer above to include that recommendation as well.

Comment: Thanks RockPaperLizard. Don't suppose [Active Disk Editor](http://www.disk-editor.org/) comes in a Portable version?

Comment: @user66001 Not to my knowledge.

Comment: Darn. On another subject, in regards to my second requirement for this software. I have tried to figure out how to match 0[Dec]/00[Hex] in a regex with this software, and tried to find more examples of regex strings apart from what Active provide in their documentation (to try and help troubleshoot my issue), without luck. As it seems this program only allows a ASCII regex, but that the ASCII representation of zero filed space is a `.`, I can't seem to match it. Also, am I missing it - How does one look at a map of the data on a drive with Active's Disk Editor (per my first requirement)?